# How to monitor who is pinging me?

Tags: networking, ping, network-monitoring

Is there a way to know who is pinging my PC on my network? Is it possible to monitor all ICMP packets? How can I do that?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, that is possible using `tcpdump`, which is a most powerful and widely used command-line packet sniffer (package analyzer) tool available on Linux.

In the terminal application of the computer you want to monitor :

```
sudo tcpdump -i ethX icmp and icmp[icmptype]=icmp-echo
```

Options:

```
-n avoid a (potentially slow) reverse DNS query
−i interface
icmp[icmptype]=icmp-echo    To print all ICMP packets that are echo requests/replies
```

The it will start listening on **ethX** and waiting for arrived packets.

Example : I have 2 pc win7 **10.1.1.8** , Ubuntu **10.1.1.57** which will monitor packets arrived :

[image]

On ubuntu :

[image]

Reference : [nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/man/tcpdump-man-page-with-examples.php)

Comment: Small correction:  `-n` shows IP instead  of *DNS names*, not MAC address. So running with -n avoid a (potentially slow) reverse DNS query.

Comment: I used wireless card (wlan0) but no return for me using Ubuntu code.

Comment: This solution only works for IPv4. To monitor IPv6 you'll need `sudo tcpdump -i ethX icmp6 and icmp6[icmptype]=icmp6-echo`

Answer (score 6):

Good workout **@nux** I liked it .

I also would like to add my trick I use to find who's pinging me by using `avahi` tool (can be installed from `Synaptic`).

When I run in terminal `avahi-browse -rat` , it automatically compiles full list of connections for example:

```
hostname = [xxx-xxx.local]
address = [xxx::x:xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx] physical
address = [xx.xx.xxx.xx] ipv4 or ipv6
port = [xxx]
txt = [xxx]
```

For example , I can always see when my Internet provider is pinging me during my session, when I run this command .

To see everything avahi can do , Run :

```
avahi-browse --help
```

Comment: i would like simple solutions without installing any package , but its okay

Comment: yes I agree it depends on everyone's desire but this tool has more functions not only pinging it allows discovering services and hosts etc

Answer (score 1):

This package must simply be installed (if you don't have it):

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

Then add this command to the `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` file:

```
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j LOG --log-prefix "LOG_IPTABLES_PING_REQUEST: "
```

To check who pings you  , just check the log file:

```
grep 'LOG_IPTABLES_PING_REQUEST: ' /var/log/messages
```

You can also use a monitoring applications such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: should that be /var/log/syslog instead?